# Books for learning classic asp, vbscript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I may have to contribute to a legacy system, classic asp with vbscript web app at work.

What are some good learning tutorials/books on this.

Please don't say you should just use .NET mvc as changing the existing system isn't an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't forget the good old [ASP For Dummies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/076450603X), read it every day for about one month and enjoyed every page of it. Clear, simple and to the point. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend this book, i used to use it as a daily reference when i started learning classic asp, pretty much like yourself i didnt have the option to use dot net

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-ASP-3-0-Programmer/dp/0764543636/ref=sr_1_11?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1297414852&sr=1-11

Also try http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp for some basic samples. If you provide more information on what you will be coding in asp i can probably suggest more sites.

Regards

Comment: For anyone visiting this question after 2012 looking for books on classic ASP (3.0) check out https://www.amazon.nl/dp/B0846NL485